# Ограничение подключений к Socket.IO по IP

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Необходимо установить ограничение на подключение к Socket.IO (node.js). Не больше 3х подключений с 1 IP.
Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: инстанс node.js один?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Штатно вроде никак, тоько вручную проверять сколько уже висит соединений, можно проверять ip складывая их в JSON или Array и сравнивая значение, например сделать **JSON**

```
{"ip" : {
"192.180.22.12" : "1",
"192.180.22.13" : "2"}
}
```

и простым ***if*** проверять сколько с этого ip соеденений, если больше 3-х то сбрасывать соеденение, главное при 0 соеденений удалять запись чтобы память не уходила на "бесконечный" JSON

ps: и честнее будет не сбрасывать соединение при превышении 3-х, а кидать сообщение о превышении допустимого кол-ва ip.